# Input Length must be a multiple of 16 when decrypting with a padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, base64

I have looked everywhere for an answer to this problem but it either doesn`t exist or im being stupid. Basically I have two methods, one to encrypt a string and one to decrypt. and in both I pass in a single string and an object of one of my classes which has the key in it. I have messed around with the placement of encoding and decoding base 64 and even not having it at all. I am at a loss. Can anyone provide any help? I have put my code for these two below:

```
public static String decrypt(String to_dec, Crypto crypt){
    try {
        Cipher chipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        chipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, crypt.app_Crypto);
        byte[] text = to_dec.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        text = chipher.doFinal(text);
        text = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text);
        String res = new String(text);
        return(res);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Unable to decrypt data");
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

as well as my method to encrypt:

```
public static String encrypt(String to_enc, Crypto crypt){
    try{
        Cipher chipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        chipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, crypt.app_Crypto);
        byte[] encrypt = Base64.getEncoder().encode(to_enc.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String text = new String(chipher.doFinal(encrypt));
        return(text);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Unable to encrypt data");
        return null;
    }


}
```

Edit: When switching where and when i decode/encode base64, sometimes it gives me a different error called badPaddingException, that the final block is not properly padded

Comment: Your problem is you're converting the encrypted `byte[]` to a string, which applies the default character encoding, thus corrupting the encrypted data, which is binary.  Encrypted data must be preserved and transmitted as bytes.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to base64 *encode* the data bytes just prior to encrypting them. That does nothing except expand the data.

Comment: Thank you for both of your help, the problem I have is I need to write each string I encrypt to a seperate line on a file and the only way I can do that is through it being a string and adding System.lineSeperator(). I am very new to java also so I apologise if I am being stupid in how I go about this.

Comment: 1. Encrypt your text, giving encrypted bytes. 2. Convert those bytes to a character string using Base64. 3. Store the Base64 character string in your system as a string.  Reverse the steps to decode.